# Vim regex to match a tab or space?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to trim the following string:

`<tab>PACKAGE MAIN` (the string starts with a tab space)

The goal is to get only `PACKAGE MAIN` as an output.

I've tried the following `VIM` functions with arguments

```
let line = substitute (line, '\t+(.*)'      , '\1', 'g')
let line = substitute (line, '\t+\(.*\)'    , '\1', 'g')
let line = substitute (line, '\t\+\(.*\)'   , '\1', 'g')
let line = substitute (line, '[\s\t]+\(.*\)', '\1', 'g')
```

(and much more)

What is the guideline for `VIM` regex to match `<tab>` or `<space>` (whitespace) chars in the `substitute` function?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `PACKAGE MAIN` might be in reality?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: taking `<tab>PACKAGE MAIN` string, the regex should return just the `PACKAGE MAIN` - (a trim function)

Comment: How many words with the package name have?  What will be the character marking the end of the package name?  You haven't addressed this in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: i tried to make my question more generic as i want to understand the vim regex guidelines.. to your question, the line may start with any whitespace and ends with a <cr> (new line)...

Comment: Something along these lines _might_ work: `:%s/\t\(.*)/\1/g`.  I use _might_ because we don't know how to identify the end of your package name in the regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify slightly the last one:

```
substitute (line, '[ \t]\+\(.*\)', '\1', 'g')
```

`+` must be prepend by `\` in order to get the magic meaning. You can use `\s` for any whitespace instead of `[ \t]` which matches only space and tab.

Comment: when i print the new line after the substitue, i get `^I^IPACKAGE MAIN` - what is the meaning of that `^I` and how can i remove it?

Comment: my mistake was that i used `"` instead of `'` in the `substitute` function call. once switched to `'` (wrapping the argument) - the method worked exactly as you said...  does `"` control the behavior of the regex?

Comment: @NirMH : No, in `"` the `\` characters escapes the characters in the string so at the end the regexp doesn't contain the backslashes at all.